# Unable to drag in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, drag-and-drop

I have the following D3 code, but I'm unable to drag the rect element successfully. (please ignore bad indentation) I'm unable to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

```
var svg = d3.select('#slider').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);


var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function (d) {
        return d;
    })
    .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged);

//Called when drag event starts. It stop the propagation of the click event
function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
}

//Called when the drag event occurs (object should be moved)
function dragged(d) {
    d.x = d3.event.x;
    d.y = d3.event.y;
    //Translate the object on the actual moved point
    d3.select(this).attr({
        transform: "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"
    });
};

svg.append('rect')
    .attr('width', 500)
    .attr('height', 250)
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('y', 50)
    .attr('fill', "transparent")
    .attr('stroke', "orange")
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
    .append("title")
    .text(function (d) {
        return "Zone 1";
    })
    .call(drag);
```

Comment: *"please ignore bad indentation"* Do you really think this carelessness will be helpful to win anyone over to spend their spare time fixing your problems? Almost every editor around will do this on a click of a button and even SO's edit function will do it for you. This is a really bad attitude. Anyway, I made the effort and put together a well-formatted and hopefully helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues:

1. You are not binding any data to your `<rect>`. Your callbacks for `.origin()` and `.on()` will fail when trying to refer to that data via their parameter `d`. You could set up an object with your `<rect>`s configuration which may be used throughout your code.

   ```
   // Configuration for rect
   var rect = {
     x: 50,
     y: 50,
     w: 500,
     h: 250,
     t: "Zone 1"
   };

   svg.selectAll("rect")
       .data([rect])   // bind your config to the rect to be appended
     .enter().append('rect')
       .attr('width', function(d) { return d.w; })
       .attr('height', function(d) { return d.h; })
   ```

   This way it is bound to your `<rect>` and will therefore be accessible even from within the drag handler. This is a very common pattern in D3.js.
2. You are calling `.drag()` after appending the `<title>` element to the `<rect>`, which adds the drag behaviour to the title instead of to the `<rect>`. To add the drag to the `<rect>` you have to move it up the call chain.

   ```
   svg.selectAll("rect").data([rect]).enter().append('rect')
        // ...
        .call(drag)
      .append("title")
        .text(function(d){return d.t;});
   ```
3. To position your `<rect>` you are using a combination of a) its attributes `x` and `y` and b) a transformation when setting `translate` while handling the drag's offset. Mixing both methods will usually screw things up. You should choose either one of those methods and then consistently stick to it.

I have set up a working snippet with some more comments explaining the changes.

```js
var width = 10000,
    height = 10000;

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);


var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(function(d) { return d; })  // this will access the bound config accessing its x and y
  .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
  .on("drag", dragged);

//Called when drag event starts. It stop the propagation of the click event
function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
}

//Called when the drag event occurs (object should be moved)
function dragged(d) {
  d.x = d3.event.x;   // update x of the config object
  d.y = d3.event.y;   // update y of the config object
  // Set new x and y on drag
  d3.select(this).attr({
    "x": d.x,
    "y": d.y
  });
};

// Configuration for rect
var rect = {
  x: 50,
  y: 50,
  w: 500,
  h: 250,
  t: "Zone 1"
};

svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data([rect])
  .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d.w; })
    .attr('height', function(d) { return d.h; })
    .attr('x', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('y', function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr('fill', "transparent")
    .attr('stroke', "orange")
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
    .call(drag)   // call this before the title is appended
  .append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.t;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```